# Moving BGA pads 0.01mm and making them smaller to work with JLCPCB capabilities

Tags: pcb, design, bga

JLCPCB has requirements that mean some BGA packages can't be used because of minimum via size and minimum track spacing and sizes of pads to vis etc.

To overcome this I came up with an idea that in theory works but I can see the possibility of issues. Is what I'm doing a good idea or completely out of line with the possibility of lots of issues?

My idea is to keep within the ball size but make some pads a little smaller and moved in a certain direction by 0.03mm maximum.  This allows room for a 0.09mm track which is the JLCPCB minimum track width.

As seen below, I'm using blue makers as ball outlines MAX SIZE, then making pads smaller and moving them to get the tracking I need on 4 layers.

[image]

Comment: Should be fine but it eats into your misalignment budget. Tighter placement control would be needed. Also, I noticed you have some blue circles without pads and route through them. If there are indeed balls there, you rely on the solder mask for insulation (bad/unreliable) and the balls could flow anywhere causing harm. It's better to provide pads even for unused balls.

Comment: @user41475. You may consider as an alternative or including what you have already established, that capped micro-vias in pads, going to the next two lower layers may also provide you with further routing paths if you find yourself constrained.